# PYTZ python is incorrectly adjusting for daylight saving on timezone Mexico_City

Tags: python, timezone, dst, timezone-offset, pytz

is PYTZ **incorrectly ** observing daylight saving for timezone Mexico_City  ?

I think daylight saving is no longer observed in Mexico asper this article:

https://time.is/time_zone_news/changes_in_mexico_time_zones

```
tz = timezone("America/New_York")
d=datetime(2023, 7, 7, 12, 0)
dt = tz.localize(d)
mx = timezone("America/Mexico_City")
dtmx = dt.astimezone(mx)
dtmx
```

gives result:

'2023-07-07T10:42:26.546648-05:00'

whereas the expectation is:

'2023-07-07T9:42:26.546648-05:00'

Comment: That couldn't be the output of _that_ code sample - as you're creating `12:00:00.000000` and then you show a result with lots of decimals.  The correct conversion should be `2023-07-07 10:00:00-06:00` and that indeed is what I get when running your code snipped on the latest version of pytz.

Comment: To verify the conversion, see https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20230707T160000&p1=179&p2=155